# How can you convert an int to an Enum without knowing the type at design time?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm currently refactoring a large codebase and converting it from vb.net to c#.  One of the functions does some funky logic around loading columns from a datasource and putting them into properties.

With vb, the creator didn't need to worry about conversions etc. but with c# I need to consider it.

So, given a piece of code like the below, I need to convert an int to the relevant enum type.

```
    public class SomeType
    {
         public SomeEnum enumValue { get; set; }

         public void SetValues()
         {
              ... GetValuesFromDataSource

              ... Iterates values

              enumValue = SetProperty(enumValue, valueFromDataSource);
         }
    }

    protected dynamic SetProperty(object oProperty, object oValue)
    {
         if (oProperty is Enum)
         {
              ... Convert oValue to the relevant enum type and assign to oProperty
         }
    }
```

Just to add some clarity.  The references to SetProperty number in the thousands, so I don't want to refactor by hand.

The oValue will come in as an int.  There is other logic in the SetProperty method for other types.  oProperty could be one of any of the hundreds of enums in the application.

Comment: How would it know what enum type to convert it to? it cant just pick one :/

Comment: What are you actually passing to the `SetProperty()` method? If it's the current value of the property, then what you're asking to do couldn't work even if you knew the `Enum` type at compile-time. If you have a _legitimate_ way to set the property dynamically, then probably all you have to do is pass the `oValue` to your setter, but maybe you have to convert using reflection. Without a better code example, it's impossible to answer your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without knowing which particular Enum type to convert to; how will you convert?

Comment: If you could the "funky logic", maybe someone around is fluent in Funk.

Comment: Added the funky logic for those funk soul brothers out there ;)

Comment: I sort of meant the original VB on the off chance your interpretation was off.  **But** since you are "sending it off to a property" that property must be of a particular Enum Type, why cant you supply it and convert/parse?

Comment: I've had to refactor a lot from the original VB, originally it was using `ref` and using a property (which isn't possible but the VB compiler converted the code).

Comment: Please post the "funky" VB.NET code

Comment: The funky VB code is simply the same, it's just that they didn't need to worry about the conversion.  it's "funky" (imo) as there are no conversions in the written code.  I don't think it's relevant, I just gave that as a reason I need to do it this way.

Comment: Someone who was interested enough in your question to read it asked for more information, but you won't give it because you don't think it's relevant. Hmmm...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update to do it more dynamically, using an out parameter for a SetProperty Method

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Entity tt = default(Entity);
        Test tester = default(Test);
        tester = SetProperty(tester, 5);
        tt = SetProperty(tt, "Test7");


        Console.WriteLine(tester);
        Console.WriteLine(tt);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static T Cast<T>(T target, object Source)
    {
        return (T)Source;
    }

    public static dynamic SetProperty<T>(T target, object source)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        Type sourceType = source.GetType();
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            Type enumType = t.GetEnumUnderlyingType();

            if (Type.Equals(sourceType, enumType))
            {
                return (T)Cast(Activator.CreateInstance(enumType), source);
            }
            if (Type.Equals(sourceType, typeof(string)))
            {
                Array names = t.GetEnumValues();
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    if (name.ToString() == source.ToString())
                    {
                        return (T)name;
                    }
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public enum Entity
    {
        Test5,
        Test7,
        Test8
    }

    public enum Test : int
    {
        Test1 = 1,
        Test2 = 5,
        Test4 = 7
    }
}
```

the output would then be:

```
Test2
Test7
```

Comment: That works if you know the type at design time, I don't.

Comment: Would you be able use this with a property rather than a variable?

Comment: @Martin, i updated it to return the value instead of using out

Comment: the oValue will be an int, not a string, that's the bit I'm stuck on to be honest.

Comment: @Martin and the enum value is not implemented as int? Then how would you like to convert? I guess in VB all that came out would have been the default value then, no? Can you add an example of how an oValue would look,  and an implemented enum?

Comment: Sorry, I've looked at the code, and it does appear to be correct.  Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to say `(T)Enum.ToObject(t, source)`. Yours looks more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If `valueFromDataSource` is an `object` and is just the boxed `enum` in question, you can use something like the following

```
if (valueFromDataSource is someEnum)
{
  return (someEnum)valueFromDataSource
}
else if (valueFromDataSource is someOtherEnum)
{
  return (someOtherEnum)valueFromDataSource            
}
```

However in your original function you're returning back an `object`, which will box it again, nothing gained

Which leads me to believe your valueFromDataSource is actually an `int`, therefore, there is no way back, and you would at best have to guess what the `enum` should be

In a design scenario, your best bet is not store the enum as an `int`, and just box it

Second would be to leave a hint to the enum type or something

**Update**

```
can you convert an int to an Enum without knowing the type at design time?
```

Unfortunately the answer is no, in VB or C# or any other language, it just cant be done

If your re-factoring code, you must have some wires crossed as the VB creator couldn't do this either

Comment: This still requires design time knowledge of the enum type.